# Regex extract parts of text after a string is matched

Tags: regex, regex-lookarounds, regex-group, qregularexpression

I have string field "event=[someevent1] ID=[000001] text=[Sample Text 123]"

I need just the part inside text that is Sample Text 123

How to extract this using regex?

I have tried `(text=).\*$` but this doesn't work.

Comment: Regex with which programming language?

Comment: `\*` will look for an asterisk. There is none. What did you intend that backslash for? You can use look-behind: `(?<=text=\[)[^]]*`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
text=\[([^\]\[]*)
```

See [this regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/5YPjJM/1).

*Details*:

- `text=\[` - a `text=[` substring
- `([^\]\[]*)` - Group 1: zero or more chars other than square brackets.

A variation of the pattern with a lookbehind:

```
(?<=text=\[)[^\]\[]+
```

It matches one or more chars other than square brackets after `text=[` string.